# Next JS:How to get the token stored in the cookie for a server side API call in Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I followed the examples in Next.js repo to setup an apollo client. The code looks like this

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import withApollo from 'next-with-apollo'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'
import cookie from 'js-cookie'
// Update the GraphQL endpoint to any instance of GraphQL that you like
const GRAPHQL_URL = 'https://myurl.com'
const token = cookie.get('token')
const link = createHttpLink({
  fetch, 
  uri: GRAPHQL_URL,
  headers: {
    authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
  },
})
export default withApollo(
  ({ initialState }) =>
    new ApolloClient({
      link: link,
      cache: new InMemoryCache()
        //  rehydrate the cache using the initial data passed from the server:
        .restore(initialState || {}),
    }),
)
```

For obvious reasons when I try to make a Graphql API call from the server side(in `getInitialProps`) it throws an error because the Bearer token is missing.
I came across `next-cookie` that can help me fetch cookies on the server-side.
But this requires the `ctx` variable. How can I access the context variable here - or is there another way to access the information stored in the cookie from the server side?

Comment: use setContext ? from 'apollo-link-context' https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/

Comment: Would this be accessible on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import nextCookie from 'next-cookies';
export default withApollo(
  ({ initialState, ctx }) => ...

  const token = nextCookie(ctx);
```

Comment: I tried this at first. But with ({ initialState, ctx }). I got an error `Cannot read property 'req' of undefined`. Apparently `ctx` is undefined here.

Comment: I was already doing this. 
In a normal page - `ctx` is present. 

But in case on `withApollo` , `ctx` is always undefined. And this doesn't work for me.

Comment: so i think `ctx` is `undefined` because `withApollo` run on client side, can you try to use `document.cookie`

Comment: For anyone looking for a solution. I ended up using js-cookie on the client-side and next-cookie on the server-side. Not sure if this is the best approach.

Added an answer. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a solution. I ended up using `js-cookie` on the client side and `next-cookie` on the server-side. Not sure if this is the best approach.

```
const token = cookie.get('token')

export default withApollo(
  ({ initialState, ctx }) =>
    new ApolloClient({
      link: createHttpLink({
        fetch,
        uri: GRAPHQL_URL,
        headers: {
          authorization: ctx ? `Bearer ${nextCookie(ctx).token}` : `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }),
      cache: new InMemoryCache()
        //  rehydrate the cache using the initial data passed from the server:
        .restore(initialState || {}),
    }),
)
```